# FactoryGirl calling `original_filename` for an object in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rspec, factory-bot

I'm working the a Documents class, trying to test it. I've defined the following factory:

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :document do
    user_id                 '6315'
    name                    'Test doc'
    description             'W9'
    filename                'test_doc.pdf'
    filetype                'file'
    filesize                500
  end

  factory :invalid_doc, parent: :document do
    filesize                5242900
  end
end
```

with the following helper method to access the right attributes in the test:

```
def build_attributes(*args)
  attrs = FactoryGirl.build(*args).attributes
  attrs.delete_if do |k, v| 
    ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"].member?(k)
  end
  paramify_values(attrs)
end
```

Before each test I run:

```
before(:each) do
  login_as_admin
  @doc = @user.documents.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:document))
end
```

where @user is set in the `login_as_admin` macro. Within my test, I'm running this:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  it "should create a new document" do
    expect{
      post :create, document: build_attributes(:document, user_id: @doc.user_id)
    }.to change(Document,:count).by(1)
  end

  it "should find the right user" do
    post :create, document: build_attributes(:document, user_id: @doc.user_id)
    assigns(:user).should eq(@user)
  end

  # some other tests...
end
```

The former test was suggested on [this article](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html), the latter is just what I think should be happening. The controller action is assigning the instance with the following:

```
@user = User.find(document[:user_id])
```

so, pretty standard. However, both of these tests throw the same error,

```
Failure/Error: post :create, document: build_attributes(:document, user_id: @doc.user_id)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass
```

but I never call that method explicitly, so is it something FactoryGirl is calling? The model is described as follows:

```
attr_accessible :description, :filename, :filesize, :filetype, :name, :user_id
```

where `:filename` is just a string. What could be going wrong here? I'm not using paperclip to upload the files, just a `file_field` in the view. I grab the path and save the file to the production server in the controller, but never call this method.

Edit:

I suppose an actual controller description might help haha

```
def create
  uploaded_file = params[:document][:file]
  document = params[:document]
  document.delete(:file)
  @user = User.find(document[:user_id])
  filepath = Rails.root.join('documents', @user.company_id.to_s, @user.id.to_s, uploaded_file.original_filename)
  %x[ mkdir #{Rails.root.join('documents', @user.company_id.to_s)} ]
  %x[ mkdir #{Rails.root.join('documents', @user.company_id.to_s, @user.id.to_s)} ]
  File.open(filepath, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_file.read)
  end
  document[:filesize]= File.size(filepath)
  document[:filetype]= File.ftype(filepath)
  document[:filename] = uploaded_file.original_filename
  d =Document.new(document)
  d.save
  redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => user.id
end
```

Please keep in mind I'm sure there are **many** things wrong with this method. I'm trying to refactor it and test as I go. For the moment, all I'm trying to do is get past this first hiccough, the `original_filename` method is being called somewhere, and I don't define it myself. Can anyone see why/where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`original_filename` is a method on an uploaded file, [see the rack documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Multipart/UploadedFile).

`filepath = Rails.root.join('documents', @user.company_id.to_s, @user.id.to_s, uploaded_file.original_filename)`

and

`document[:filename] = uploaded_file.original_filename`

In the controller are getting the original filename, since when a file gets uploaded it gets an ugly temp filename for storage you want to use the original filename to make it readable and accurate.

Consider using the `fixture_file_upload` helper in rspec. Here is an example spec:

```
    expect {
      post :create, document: attributes_for(:document, user_id: @doc.user_id, file: fixture_file_upload('spec/assets/documents/test_doc.pdf', 'appliation/pdf'))
    }.to change(Document, :count).by(1)
```

And place a test pdf in `spec/assets/documents/test_doc.pdf`

Comment: Thanks so much! I have another question jumping off this response. I created the the directories and put a file in it, and the code is actually looking for a path called `#{Rails.root}/spec/fixturesspec/assets/documents` when I created `#{Rails.root}/spec/assets/documents`. Did I create the wrong thing? Or do I need to specify another configuration somewhere?

Comment: My guess is that you are using different configurations for rspec than I am familiar with :) I would change the spec to look for `fixture_file_upload('/documents/test_doc.pdf', 'application/pdf')` and put the file in `{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documents/` which should work based on your config.

Comment: You sir, are the bomb.com!

Comment: All of a sudden, these tests started failing, saying I can't assign a protected attribute, `file`. The only attributes I have that include "file" are `filename`, `filesize`, and `filetype`. Should I be setting them to the `fixture_file_upload` method?

Comment: That means that when you are trying to create the document you are trying to assign :file in that hash, which is either non-existant or attr_protected. If it exists, and you really want to assign it set `attr_accessible :file` in your model.

Comment: I understand that, but it shouldn't need to be. I'm never accessing it. The third line of my create action is supposed to remove that key,value from the hash that ultimately gets assigned to the new record, but somehow it isn't being removed? Or some other line in the action is trying to validate the record before it's removed.

Comment: You might have altered your factory to try to assign file? Look at the trace of the error, it should tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Turns out, I have changed some CanCan configuration for the class, and that class was throwing the error. Wouldn't have found that without the trace, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile.new(path)
```

for your test.